# Client grid to work with javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, binding, grid

I need a client side grid to work with javascript arrays. I need editing, filtering and sorting functionality with minimal configuration. An example would be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer the below example (!oops but only works with IE )will develop crossbrowser soon. http://demo.wpage.in/pages/admin/company.aspx best tested in I.E8.0. use compatiable mode in higher -snaidua@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much easier you want these guys to make it for you.

[Here's a fiddle with an editable KendoUI grid and the data is set in the JS code.](http://jsfiddle.net/schapman/kvXVf/)

I didn't hook up the save methods but you can find out how to do that at the [KendoUI site here.](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html)